# pip install a specific version of PyQt5

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am using spyder & want to install finplot. However when I did this I could not open spyder and had to uninstall & reinstall anconda.

The problem is to do with PyQt5 as I understand. The developer of finplot said that one solution would be to install PyQt5 version 5.9.

> Error: spyder 4.1.3 has requirement pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you'll have pyqt5 5.13.0 which is incompatible

My question is how would I do this? To install finplot I used the line below,

> pip install finplot

Is there a way to specify that it should only install PyQt5?

Comment: finplot just moved over to pyqt6. Just let me know if there are lingering incompatibilities.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand you just want to install PyQT5 version 9.0.You can try this below if you got pip installed on your machine

> pip install PyQt5==5.9

Edit: First you need to uninstall your pyQT5 5.13

> pip uninstall PyQt5

Comment: Just to extend a bit: Generally I find it helps a lot to install requirements in a fresh virtual environment with one single pip call, e.g. `pip install finplot pyqt5`. Then pip usually takes care of compatibility.

Comment: I think finplot installs PyQt5 as part of the installation. I was hoping to be able to specify when I install finplot that it should install PyQt5 version 5.9

Comment: I agree with fischmalte. You should use virtual environments if you want to use two versions of pyqt for different projects in this situation. or you can build it from github before doing that just change the PyQT version in setup.py it might work.